# how to fix: executio failed for task app:compiledebugRenderStript

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

android studio is showing unknow constant tag 0 in class file /com/android/internal/compiler/RenderScriptProcesor$Abi
why is showing this error, i started a new project with default configurations of android studio and and continues showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following exists in your build.gradle file:

**renderscriptTargetApi**

**renderscriptSupportModeEnabled**

**renderscriptNdkModeEnabled**

if so, remove it.